# 404 errer due to .htaccess file

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, google-search-console

I have a website. In this website I have some 404 file not found errors as per my google webmaster, although all the files are present. They are as follow:

```
http://firstcovers.net/http//firstcovers.net/
http://firstcovers.net/category/1/http//firstcovers.net/
http://firstcovers.net/category/8/4/http//firstcovers.net/
http://firstcovers.net/category/17/2/http//firstcovers.net/
http://firstcovers.net/category/20/2/http//firstcovers.net/
http://firstcovers.net/facebook-cover/1317/privacy.php
http://firstcovers.net/facebook-cover/1317/terms.php
http://firstcovers.net/facebook-cover/1286/privacy.php
http://firstcovers.net/facebook-cover/338/terms.php
```

The structure of .htaccess file is as follow:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html.var index.htm index.html index.shtml index.xhtml index.wml index.perl index.pl index.plx index.ppl index.cgi index.jsp index.js index.jp index.php4 index.php3 index.php index.phtml default.htm default.html home.htm index.php5 Default.html Default.htm home.html
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
#AddHandler fcgid-script .php
RewriteEngine On


RewriteRule ^latest.html /index.php?latest=y [L]
RewriteRule ^random.html /index.php?random=y [L]
RewriteRule ^showall.html /index.php?showall=y [L]
RewriteRule ^about.html /about.php [L]
RewriteRule ^userupload.html /userupload.php [L]
RewriteRule ^get-timeline.html /how.php [L]

RewriteRule ^facebook-cover-([0-9]+).html /detailpage.php?cp=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^facebook-cover/([0-9]+)/([^/]*).html /detailpage.php?cp=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^preview/([0-9]+)/([^/]*).html /detailpage.php?preview=y&cp=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/([^/]*).html /index.php?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*).html /index.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^cover-([0-9]+).html  /image.php?picID=$1 [L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^css/(.*\.css) /combine.php?type=css&files=$1
RewriteRule ^javascript/(.*\.js) /combine.php?type=javascript&files=$1

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css
<FilesMatch "\\.(js|css|html|htm|php|xml)$">
# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>

Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2030 20:00:00 GMT"
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .(gif|jpe?g?|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^https?://([^.]+.)?firstcovers. [NC]
RewriteRule .(gif|jpe?g?|png)$ - [F,NC,L]
</ifModule>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.google.com/reader/view/.*$ [NC]
# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

FileETag MTime Size
```

I have tried my best to change the regular expression of the .htaccess file. But still I am doing some mistake. I am unable to trace that mistake.

I request the members of this site to help me.

**Thanks in advance.

Your friend.

V K Saw.**

Comment: what internal urls u r talking about? There is no "category" or "facebook-cover" folder in my root directory. I am just redirecting them. but they are actually not getting done.

Comment: Yes that's what I need to know i.e. what these should be rewritten/redirected to?

Comment: This is my friend's website. He has get it done by some developer but he is no longer in contact, So I am unable to figure out that. but since your reputation looks good, you can be able to figure that out, after seeing the complete 404 not found list. If u want, I can pay. tell me the charges.

Comment: I wouldn't have enquired if I had understood it all. There are so many other website where you can pay and get the work done. Here we don't do it for money, we just try to help the community.

Comment: I respect this Anubhava, but can you get me out of this situation.

Comment: You have a rewriteCond that serve no purpose (and outside the ifmodule). This could cause more harm than good... "RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.google.com/reader/view/.*$ [NC]"

Comment: Can you tell me under which server is this app running? Because rules can vary from server to server.

Comment: can you please include screenshot from Webmaster tools listing these errors

Answer (score 3):

For the following 404s

```
http://firstcovers.net/facebook-cover/1317/privacy.php
http://firstcovers.net/facebook-cover/1317/terms.php
http://firstcovers.net/facebook-cover/1286/privacy.php
http://firstcovers.net/facebook-cover/338/terms.php
```

Modify your `facebook-cover` rule to match on `.php` URLs as well.

```
RewriteRule ^facebook-cover/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)\.(php|html)$ /detailpage.php?cp=$1 [L]
```

The rest of the 404 links

```
http://firstcovers.net/http//firstcovers.net/
http://firstcovers.net/category/1/http//firstcovers.net/
http://firstcovers.net/category/8/4/http//firstcovers.net/
http://firstcovers.net/category/17/2/http//firstcovers.net/
http://firstcovers.net/category/20/2/http//firstcovers.net/
```

aren't being generated by your .htaccess file. Check your php code for incorrect generation of URLs. Somewhere its appending `http//firstcovers.net/` at the end. You're using some custom tags (like `<g:plusone>`) and this could be a bug in one such tag library as well.

Answer (score 1):

These are your provided url of 404 errors

```
http://firstcovers.net/http//firstcovers.net/
http://firstcovers.net/category/1/http//firstcovers.net/
http://firstcovers.net/category/8/4/http//firstcovers.net/
http://firstcovers.net/category/17/2/http//firstcovers.net/
http://firstcovers.net/category/20/2/http//firstcovers.net/
http://firstcovers.net/facebook-cover/1317/privacy.php
http://firstcovers.net/facebook-cover/1317/terms.php
http://firstcovers.net/facebook-cover/1286/privacy.php
http://firstcovers.net/facebook-cover/338/terms.php
```

There are two sets of problems in provided urls. Let us solve the issue one by one. The first set of urls are:

```
http://firstcovers.net/facebook-cover/1317/privacy.php
http://firstcovers.net/facebook-cover/1317/terms.php
http://firstcovers.net/facebook-cover/1286/privacy.php
http://firstcovers.net/facebook-cover/338/terms.php
```

I have visited your webpage and found the code as:

```
<a class="uibutton" href="#" onClick="newInvite(); return false;">Invite</a>
<a class="uibutton icon secure" onclick="privacy(); return false;">Privacy</a>
<a class="uibutton" onclick="terms(); return false;">Terms</a>
```

You have to change the code to resolve your problem as under:

```
<a class="uibutton" href="#" onClick="newInvite(); return false;">Invite</a>
<a class="uibutton icon secure" href="#"  onclick="privacy(); return false;">Privacy</a>
<a class="uibutton" href="#" onclick="terms(); return false;">Terms</a>
```

In your code `href="#"` code is missing that is causing the problem for first set of urls. As in your urls the Invite is not included as 404 errors, thus it will resolve first set of url problem.

Second set of urls:

```
http://firstcovers.net/http//firstcovers.net/
http://firstcovers.net/category/1/http//firstcovers.net/
http://firstcovers.net/category/8/4/http//firstcovers.net/
http://firstcovers.net/category/17/2/http//firstcovers.net/
http://firstcovers.net/category/20/2/http//firstcovers.net/
```

First thing first here to mention, your website is dynamic and you are generating the sitemap through third party tools such as python script or may be other, Which in turn is accessing the apache access logs. Since, the url is unique the url is added in sitemap and there is no url thus 404 error.

There are two solutions to your problem:

1. Either drop the un-required url such as these causing problems from sitemap. For doing that you need to view/read the third party tool documentaion.
2. Wherever in url your own site name appears again you redirect them to homepage url and since you have the knowledge of regular expression thus it would not be a problem for you.